# Activate certain image in a picture tag by using class

Tags: css, image

I am using the picture tag to toggle between two images. Image 1 is 240x240 and will display when the window is 32em and above. Image 2 is 112x112 and will display when it's under 32em.

I am trying to apply a class .active to the div so Image 1 will show and Image 2 will hide.

```
<div>
    <picture>
        <source media="(min-width: 32em)" srcset="http://via.placeholder.com/240x240/AEAEAE/000000?text=Ambassador+Image+(240x240)">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/112x112"/>
    </picture>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what are your constraints with the HTML, but if it's possible, I'd suggest using two `img` nodes directly inside the div, and to put our CSS inside a `style` node.

For example :

```css
#img240 {
 width:240px;
 height:240px;
}
 
#img112 {
 display: none;
 width:112px;
 height:112px;
}

@media (max-width: 32em) {
 #img240 {
  display: none;
 }
 
 #img112 {
  display: block;
 }
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img id="img240" src="..." alt="240x240" />
    <img id="img112" src="..." alt="112x112" />
</div>
```

I'm not familiar enough with the `picture` node and with inline CSS media queries to give an answer closer to your existing code. My apologies!

Answer (score 1):

Image 1 is shown with min-width:32em and image 2 shown for width below 32em without the active class on div.

```html
<div>
  <picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 32em)" srcset="https://picsum.photos/240">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/112" />
  </picture>
</div>
```